# How to mouseover multiple elements in one function

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to mouseOver each picture without only the last picture in my funtion showingup.

---

Here is my HTML

```html
<div id = "image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>
    
<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
<img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
<img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Here is my Javascript

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg)";
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "Styling with a Bandana";  
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG)";
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "With My Boy";  
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg)";
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "Young Puppy";  
}


function unDo(){
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage="url('')";
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML= "Hover over an image below to display here.";
}
```

Comment: This is so beginner, its not worth an answer ;) In your update function, you override the values three times, but instead you want to set data from your param, like  `document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = previewPic.src` ... hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `event` provided by `onmouseover` to target the image you want. Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-p2ynt5?file=index.html) and here is the code :

html :

```html
<img
  class="preview"
  alt="Styling with a Bandana"
  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"
  onmouseover="upDate(event)"
  onmouseout="unDo()"
/>
<img
  class="preview"
  alt="With My Boy"
  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG"
  onmouseover="upDate(event)"
  onmouseout="unDo()"
/>
<img
  class="preview"
  src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg"
  alt="Young Puppy"
  onmouseover="upDate(event)"
  onmouseout="unDo()"
/>
<hr />
<div id="image" style="display: inline-block">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>
```

Note the `event` that is passed in the `upDate` function.

js :

```js
  // use the event to target the image you want to display
  function upDate(e) {
    // do not repeat yourself, use a variable to store your elements
    let imageDisplay = document.getElementById('image');
    // Get values of the image your are hovering
    var imageInfo = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Set your values width and height
    imageDisplay.style.width = `${imageInfo.width * 2}px`;
    imageDisplay.style.height = `${imageInfo.height * 2}px`;

    // Set the background and its placement
    imageDisplay.style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.target.src})`;
    imageDisplay.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';

    // Write the text you want
    imageDisplay.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
  }

  function unDo() {
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML =
      'Hover over an image below to display here.';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this way.

- group all images with a div
- use event delegation

sample code:

```js
const
  imageDisplay  = document.querySelector('div#image > img')
, previewImages = document.querySelector('div#previews')
  ;
previewImages.onmouseover = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('img')) return
  
  imageDisplay.src = e.target.src  
  }
previewImages.onmouseout = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('img')) return

  imageDisplay.src = ''  
  }
```

```css
div#image  {
  --szH : 325px;
  --szW : 288px;
  position   : relative;
  display    : block;
  width      : var(--szW);
  height     : var(--szH);
  overflow   : hidden;
  background : lightgray;
  }
div#image > * {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  }
div#image > img {
  width      : var(--szW);
  height     : var(--szH);
  }
div#previews > img {
  width  : 100px;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
div#image > span {
  padding : 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="previews">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg"  alt="Styling with a Bandana" >
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" alt="With My Boy" >
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" >
</div>
<div id="image">
  <span>Hover over an image below to display here.</span>
  <img src="" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with or without jquery, but I prefer the latter because it saves you a lot of hassle + you will not need to call the function from each element, instead you'll be using a method.

Styling:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.reel {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20%;
    bottom: 0%;
    justify-content: center;
}
#image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: max-content;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
#text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 1%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
}
```

1st method's HTML:

```
<img id="image">
<div id="text">Hover over an image below to display here</div>
<div class="reel">
    <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide()">
    <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide()">
    <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide()">
</div>
```

1st method's JavaScript:
var image = document.getElementById("image"),
text = document.getElementById("text");

```
function show(pic) {
    image.src = pic.src;
    text.innerHTML = pic.alt;
}

function hide() {
    image.src = "";
    text.innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here";
}
```

---

2nd method's HTML (without event listeners):

```
<img id="image">
<div id="text">Hover over an image below to display here</div>
<div class="reel">
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg">
    <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG">
    <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy">
</div>
```

2nd method's JavaScript:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image"),
    text = document.getElementById("text");

$(document).on('mouseover', '.preview', function() {
    image.src = this.src;
    text.innerHTML = this.alt;
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.preview', function() {
    image.src = "";
    text.innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here";
});
```

JQuery even allows you to specify several elements for the same event. You can do it by class, ID or tag name  like so:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.preview, .container, div, a, body, #image, #text', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
});
```

In this example, the background color will change to black if the mouse hovers over elements with a class of preview or container, or with a tag name of div, a or body, or with an ID of image or text, all within one line.

The results are the same in both methods.

[Result preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKFmo.png)